# div fades out if mouse does not hover over it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want code in which a div fades out if mouse does not hover over it. This is the code which makes the div visible. As soon as it is displayed it fades out. I want that if a user hovers over it while it is fading out it stops fading and becoming as it was initially. And then as user hovers out of it it fades again.

```
$('#popuup_div').css({left:leftVal,top:topVal}).show().fadeOut(2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop) function which stops all animations taking place on an element. Use it in a [mouseover()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) event handler and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/6WMDz/1/

```
$('#popuup_div').on('mouseover', function() {
     $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

​

I have used `mouseover` to `fadeIn` the div.
You can also use `stop`, but it is not resetting the display to initial state.